# Over 100% of stage done during DROP COLUMN

Tags: innodb, database-performance, mariadb, xtradb

I'm running a DROP COLUMN on the primary key column (I know, it's terrible but I had to do it). There's a progress indicator:

```
Stage: 1 of 2 'copy to tmp table'    107% of stage done
```

I haven't been modifying the data during the operation. Why would it be over 100% finished? Will it ever stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Innodb (and in turn xtradb) do not keep running counts of the number of rows in a table.  The number of rows displayed when doing a `SHOW TABLE STATUS` is purely an estimate.

Likely your tool wth the progress indicator is using this information to determine what 100% is.  Since it's an estimate, so is the percentage complete.

[This article on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926259/why-is-the-estimated-rows-count-very-different-in-phpmyadmin-results) goes into further detail.